# Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

**I have this code**

```
  @Where(
    ['owner', 'Manager', 'Email', 'productEmail', 'Region'],
    (keys: string[], values: unknown) => {
      const query = {};

      keys.forEach((k: string) => {            
    }
  )
```

**when I enabled strict rule for type checks it's complaining**

```
Argument of type '(keys: string[], values: unknown) => {}' is not assignable to parameter of type '(key: string | string[], values: unknown) => unknown'.
  Types of parameters 'keys' and 'key' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.ts
```

when i change keys type to `(keys: string | string[], values: unknown) =>`

I am getting another error

```
Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.
  Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string'.ts
```

**Can someone have any idea on how to resolve this issue.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that Typescript is trying to save you from accidentally calling `forEach` on `keys` when it's type `string`, since it wouldn't have the `forEach` property and would fail at runtime. Is the `@Where` decorator one that you implemented? Or from a third-party package?

If you need to retain the type `string | string[]` whilst also calling `forEach`, you'll need to make sure `keys` is an Array before calling that method, as follows.

```js
if (Array.isArray(keys)) {
    keys.forEach(...);
}
```

Comment: @Where decorator is from third-party ORM library